# Source not found in Eclipse for simple 1 liner code

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed Eclipse and wrote very simple code and pressed debug.

I see an unexpected error: Eclipse switches to debug (which is fine) but shows a new tab as below:
[image]
I looked up this and see that some folks have changes the build path, my buildpath looks ok - it contains the top folder of my project which contains the code in its src folder.

any ideas.

----UPDATE----

Apologies, i forgot to add my code.

```
public class essenceApiTest {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //File file = new File("C:\\Users\\me\\file.xml");
        try {
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Fail: "+e.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("Essence Api test complete");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add source jar into the path http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-source-attachment.htm

Comment: Usually we filter out standard Java classes from debugging process and assume that they are all correct. You can do it by adding filters to `java.*` `javax.*` (or even `sun.*`) packages. Try going to preferences -> Java -> Debug -> Step Filtering and add filters for these packages. Also make sure to select `Use Step Filters` and `Step through filters` options.

Answer (score 0):

This simply means you don't have the source code of the class you are trying to debug. Try importing to your eclipse workspace.

Comment: See the code - what source file could i be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Install the full jdk with sources, and configure this as your JRE and compiler under Preferences->Java->Installed JRE.

You probaly just have the JRE deployed on your machine.

Comment: How can i check if i do have the full jdkl (which im nearly sure i do)  -system env variables path?

Comment: JRE (Default), JRE8 installed

Comment: So there you are, install the JDK instead of the JRE, this is more appropriate for development purposes.

Comment: I'm sure i have JDK on my system already, any idea how i can find it?

Comment: window->Preferences->Java->Installed JRE, click Add, browse to installation folder of the JDK (on win, somewhere in Program files/Java), check the JDK as default runtime, Apply, Ok

Comment: Found it - selected C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60 and ran debug again and same issue